# How to click radio button in cucumber when radio button id is increasing

Tags: java, selenium, radio-button, cucumber

I am creating a class in cucumber for testing a page.
I have to enter data (all Strings - like name, city, country etc) in 4 text boxes and hit Add button. Once i hit add button the data is added and displayed beside the textboxes.

The data from all 4 boxes will be displayed and a radio button will be added for that row.
e.g.

```
o     AAA    DDDD   11111    DDDD
o     BBB    GGGG   22222    TTTTT
o     DDD    PPPP   85858    MMM
```

Assume o is radio button here.

When i inspect the element its like below. The id is incrementing for every record added.

```
<input id = radio0 name= radio type= radio >
<input id = radio1 name= radio type= radio >
<input id = radio2 name= radio type= radio >
```

There is Edit and Delete button also there.

I have select the row of data and either edit or delete
Edit will again populate the text boxes and i will edit the data again if i have to.

Delete will simply delete.

My question is how to click radio button.
I am not able to click radio button through selenium.

Comment: Cucumber has nothing to do with clicking radio buttons or any other web element interaction, for that matter.  Why are you unable to click the radio button with Selenium?  What have you tried?  Show us your work.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am workinng on a webpage where i have to enter data in 4 text boxes and then perform edit and delete on the data that is added. Data is added in block. All data added is displayed with a radio button so i can delete or edit whole row of data. Now i am trying with xpath with //input[@id=radio0]. But its not working. How to click any (radio with radio0 or radio1 or radio2) radio button ??

Comment: Place the ID inside single quotes: `//input[@id='radio1']`

Comment: Using java, if your webdriver is called **driver** then `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='radio0']")).click();`

Comment: Hi thanks. Its working fine now. I used the same xpath.